# Unique Particle Attribution error

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, altova

**Aim:**
I am having an existing standard XSD called Schema1.xsd. 
I want to extend the complexType("tElementWithIDAndName") of Schema1.xsd in complexType("TVDSection") of Schema2.xsd.

When i try to validate the Schema2.xsd in Altova XMLSpy/oXygen xml editor, I am getting the following error:

**Error:**
[Xerces] cos-nonambig: "http://www.mySchema.com/Generic/1":element1 and WC[##other:"http://www.mybasic.com/1",""] (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.

Schema1.xsd:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.mybasic.com/1" 
                       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                       xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"  
                       targetNamespace="http://www.mybasic.com/1" 
                       elementFormDefault="qualified" 
                       version="0.1">

                <xs:complexType name="tElementWithIDAndName">
                    <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="additionalName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                          <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="strict" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:schema>
```

Schema2.xsd:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.mySchema.com/Generic/1" 
                       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                       xmlns:myBasic="http://www.mybasic.com/1"
                       targetNamespace="http://www.mySchema.com/Generic/1"
                       elementFormDefault="qualified" version="0.1">

                <xs:import namespace="http://www.mybasic.com/1" schemaLocation="schema.xsd"/>

                <xs:element name="Element1" type="TVDSection"/>
                <xs:complexType name="TVDSection">
                    <xs:complexContent>
                        <xs:extension base="myBasic:tElementWithIDAndName">
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:complexContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:schema>
```

I don't know where/how this is violating unique particle attribution.
Please help me to resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content model can be paraphrased as "any number of elements named p:additionalName, followed by any number of elements provided they are not in namespace 'p', followed by any number of elements named q:element1, ". Now, if a q:element1 element is encountered, the validator doesn't know whether to put it in the second group (any number of elements that aren't in namespace 'p') or the third group (anything named q:element1). Hence the ambiguity.

In XSD 1.1 the spec has been changed so that in this situation, where there is a specific particle and a wildcard particle that both match, the specific particle is always chosen in preference. So one solution is simply to move to XSD 1.1. If you want to stay with XSD 1.0, you need to change the xs:any wildcard so it puts more constraints on the namespace of the allowed elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, i could not change the schema1.xsd as it is a standard xsd for our project coming from another team. Also my existing tool do not support XSD 1.1. 
Any idea to come out of this problem.

Comment: Why do you want to extend the complex type in schema1.xsd? It already allows wildcard content after the additionalName element, why do you need to change it at all?

Comment: As for "my existing tool does not support XSD 1.1", the answer of course is to switch to a tool vendor that is actively developing their product and keeping up with the latest standards.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information Michael Kay.